# How to create a matrix of matrix that contains a list of all possible scenarios in which 18 cards can be distributed to 6 players equally

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I am looking for a way to generate the list of all the possible scenarios in which 18 cards can be distributed to 6 players. Then I want to loop through the list and delete all the instances that match certain criteria.

I am working on an algorithm that can help me predict cards that are kept in the envelope. I want to find out the list of all the possible scenarios in which the cards can be distributed to all the six players.

For eg the list of 18 cards looks something like this

```
master_list =list (['w1','w2','w3',....,'l9'])
```

I want an output like this

```
 [[['player 1' 'w1' 'w2' 'l1']
  ['player 2' 'w3' 's1' 's2']
  ['player 3' 'l2' 'l3' 's3']
  ['player 4' 'l4' 's5' 's4']
  ['player 5' 'w4' 'l5' 'l6']
  ['player 6' 'w5' 'l7' 'l8']]

  [['player 1' 'w5' 'w2' 'l1']
  ['player 2' 'w4' 's1' 's2']
  ['player 3' 'l4' 'l3' 's3']
  ['player 4' 'l2' 's5' 's4']
  ['player 5' 'w3' 'l5' 'l6']
  ['player 6' 'w1' 'l7' 'l8']]

  ....
  .... all the possible scenarios
```

This is what i have done so far..

import all the necessary libs

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations 
import operator as op
from functools import reduce


#master_list = list of all the cards
#new_master = list of all the cards left after i reveal my cards
#comb = all possible combinations based on new_master list
#pos_env_comb = all possible candidates for envelope
```

Take input from player 1 and then remove those cards from the master list and create a new masters list

```
print("input your cards with spaces")
input_list = [str(x) for x in input().split()]
master_list = list(['w1','w2','w3','w4','w5','w6',....,'l8','l9'])
new_master = np.setdiff1d(master_list,input_list)
print(new_master)
pos_env_comb = list()
```

Create all the possible combinations that can go in the envelope

```
comb = list(combinations(new_master, 3)) 
print(len(comb))

# Print the obtained combinations 
for i in comb:
    w = 0
    s = 0
    l = 0
    c = 0
    for j in i:
        if(j[0][0] == 'w'):
            w = w + 1

        elif(j[0][0] == 's'):
            s = s + 1

        else:
            l = l + 1

        if(w == 1 and s == 1 and l == 1):
            pos_env_comb.append(i)

print(len(pos_env_comb))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), then if you have a specific issue you should post a question that explains the problem you are having along with the code you have attempted.

Comment: I have updated the code.. can you please check and help me plz?

Answer (score 0):

First let's understand how many different scenarios you are talking about. There are 18 cards in the deck, the first player drafts 3 of them. There are (18 choose 3) different ways to pick them. Then, the next player drafts another 3 cards, which can be done in (15 choose 3) different ways. The final number is given by:

```
(18 choose 3) * (15 choose 3)* (12 choose 3)* (9 choose 3)* (6 choose 3)* (3 choose 3) = 137225088000 = 1.37225088 * 10^11
```

Thats the unique number of different drafts from the 6 players combined. Note that permutations of the chosen cards aren't (and shouldn't) being considered.

That's a lot of combinations, you will require a lot of time to compute them. Since you have asked to get all of them into a list of lists, I will show you how to do just that, however, keep in mind you are going to need a lot of available RAM memory to hold it:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict

def _card_round_to_list(d):
    result = list()
    for k, draft in d.items():
        player = [k]
        for card in draft:
            player.append(card)
        result.append(player)
    return result

available_cards = ['card0', 'card1', 'card2', 'card3', 'card4', 'card5', 'card6', 'card7', 'card8', 'card9', 'card10', 'card11', 'card12', 'card13', 'card14', 'card15', 'card16', 'card17']
draft_size = 3
n_players = 6
all_combinations = list()

'''
# TEST scenario: meant for quick computation and small RAM memory usage
available_cards = ['card0', 'card1', 'card2', 'card3', 'card4', 'card5']
draft_size = 1
'''

for draft1 in combinations(available_cards, draft_size):
    deck = list()
    for card in available_cards:
        deck.append(card)

    curr_round = defaultdict(list)
    player1_draft = list(draft1)

    curr_round['player1'] = player1_draft
    for card in player1_draft:
        deck.remove(card)

    for draf2 in combinations(deck, draft_size):
        player2_draft = list(draf2)
        curr_round['player2'] = player2_draft
        for card in player2_draft:
            deck.remove(card)

        for draf3 in combinations(deck, draft_size):
            player3_draft = list(draf3)
            curr_round['player3'] = player3_draft
            for card in player3_draft:
                deck.remove(card)

            for draf4 in combinations(deck, draft_size):
                player4_draft = list(draf4)
                curr_round['player4'] = player4_draft
                for card in player4_draft:
                    deck.remove(card)

                for draf5 in combinations(deck, draft_size):
                    player5_draft = list(draf5)
                    curr_round['player5'] = player5_draft
                    for card in player5_draft:
                        deck.remove(card)

                    curr_round['player6'] = deck.copy()
                    all_combinations.append(_card_round_to_list(curr_round))

                    del curr_round['player6']

                    del curr_round['player5']
                    for card in player5_draft:
                        deck.append(card)

                del curr_round['player4']
                for card in player4_draft:
                    deck.append(card)

            del curr_round['player3']
            for card in player3_draft:
                deck.append(card)

        del curr_round['player2']
        for card in player2_draft:
            deck.append(card)

    del curr_round['player1']
    for card in player1_draft:
        deck.append(card)


print(all_combinations)
```

In practice, unless have an awesome machine, you'll need to adapt the above code to store each parcial result in the hard disk once each combination is ready. That can be done specifically at line 62. In addition, for efficiency purposes, keep in mind you should avoid the strings represeting the card names, you should prefer ints instead, it should save a considerable amount of memory, and the same goes for player names.

Furthermore, I should have implemented the above code for an arbitrary amount of different card players, however, this is a "quick & dirty" version.

Hope you enjoy,

Cheers!